# How to make an json array inside another json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working on android app with json data. For that I had make webservices using php and json. In which I got results but its not proper for my app. Below is my code:

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");
$query= "SELECT * from zone";
try {
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = @$stmt->execute($query_params);   
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
$zone["success"] = 0;
$zone["message"] = "Database Error!";
die(json_encode($zone));
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($rows) {

$zone["posts"]   = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post  = array();
    $post["zone_id"]=$row["zone_id"];
    $post["zone_name"]=$row["zone_name"];
    $post["zone_turn"]=$row["zone_turn"];
    $post["zone_charge"]=$row["zone_charge"];

    $query1= "SELECT * from pincode_master where zone_id=".$row['zone_id']."";
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query1);
        $result = @$stmt->execute($query_params);   
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $zone["success"] = 0;
        $zone["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($zone));
    }
    $rows1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if ($rows1) {
        $zone["posts1"]   = array();

        foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {
            $post1  = array();
            //$post1["zone_id"]=$row1["zone_id"];
            $post1["pincode_number"]=$row1["pincode_number"];
            //echo $post["pincode_number"];

             array_push($zone["posts1"], $post1);
        }

    }
     array_push($zone["posts"], $post,$zone["posts1"]);
    }  
  echo json_encode($zone);
  } else {
  $zone["success"] = 0;
  $zone["message"] = "No Zone asssign for this day!";
  }
 ?>
```

From above code I got below json array. It will contain all data in one array except the pincode number because I got it from another table.:

```
{"posts[{"zone_id":"2","zone_name":"A","zone_turn":"Monday,Thrusday","zone_charge":"15"},[{"pincode_number":"390007"},{"pincode_number":"390016"},{"pincode_number":"390021"},{"pincode_number":"390023"}],{"zone_id":"3","zone_name":"B","zone_turn":"Tuesday,Friday","zone_charge":"15"},[{"pincode_number":"390001"},{"pincode_number":"390004"},{"pincode_number":"390006"},{"pincode_number":"390010"},{"pincode_number":"390018"},{"pincode_number":"390019"},{"pincode_number":"390020"},{"pincode_number":"390022"}],{"zone_id":"7","zone_name":"W","zone_turn":"Saturday,Sunday,Friday","zone_charge":"15"},[{"pincode_number":"390001"},{"pincode_number":"390004"},{"pincode_number":"390006"},{"pincode_number":"390010"},{"pincode_number":"390018"},{"pincode_number":"390019"},{"pincode_number":"390020"},{"pincode_number":"390022"}],{"zone_id":"8","zone_name":"X","zone_turn":"Wednesday,Saturday,Sunday","zone_charge":"15"},[{"pincode_number":"390001"},{"pincode_number":"390004"},{"pincode_number":"390006"},{"pincode_number":"390010"},{"pincode_number":"390018"},{"pincode_number":"390019"},{"pincode_number":"390020"},{"pincode_number":"390022"}]],"posts1":[{"pincode_number":"390001"},{"pincode_number":"390004"},{"pincode_number":"390006"},{"pincode_number":"390010"},{"pincode_number":"390018"},{"pincode_number":"390019"},{"pincode_number":"390020"},{"pincode_number":"390022"}]}
```

But I want below one:

```
{"posts[{"zone_id":"2","zone_name":"A","zone_turn":"Monday,Thrusday","zone_charge":"15","pincode_number":{"390007","390016","390021"}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new array like this, `$zone["posts1"]   = array();` to add your pincodes, you can simply append the pincode data as well in to your already existing $post array.

```
$post  = array();
$post["zone_id"]=$row["zone_id"];
$post["zone_name"]=$row["zone_name"];
$post["zone_turn"]=$row["zone_turn"];
$post["zone_charge"]=$row["zone_charge"];
.
.
.

$rows1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if ($rows1) {

        foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {

            $post["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"];

        }

    }
    array_push($zone["posts"], $post);
   }
```

Comment: $post["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"]; will show error @Vincent

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\Web Service\zone.php on line 45

Comment: kindly suggest me the way

Comment: strange...is this `$post["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"];` your line number 45 ?

Comment: yes :) what piece of code do you have on your line number 45 ?

Comment: apparently you have not balanced the braces hence the error, modify it to what I wrote in the code `$post["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"];` , you have an extra ' [ ' (after "pincode number") in your code

Comment: Happy to help Nidhi :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make `$post1` a multi-dimensional array and `array_push` after and OUTSIDE the foreach. Like below:

```
    foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {
        $post1  = array();
        $post1["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"];

    }
    array_push($zone["posts1"], $post1);
```

Comment: $post1["pincode_number"][] = $row1["pincode_number"];
will show error @isnisn